# Javascript addEventListener not working properly

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

So i'm having trouble with the event so, normally i try to create an event if we have more than 1 image in the array so i can `mouseenter` and display another one but currently i don't know why but when we `mouseenter` the preview (image) it giving the latest result from the array while we still inside the loop ?

```js
    var product_type = "";
        for(let i = 0; i < this.products_list.length; i++){
            var row = this.products_list[i], self = this;
            if(row.product_type != product_type){
                product_type = row.product_type;  
                var sub_title = document.createElement("h2"),
                    separator = document.createElement("hr"),
                    display_list = document.createElement("ul");
                    sub_title.id = product_type;
                    sub_title.innerHTML = localeString.get(product_type);
                    display_list.id = product_type+"-list";

                    this.catalog.appendChild(sub_title);
                    this.catalog.appendChild(separator);
                    this.catalog.appendChild(display_list);     
            }
            var product = document.createElement("li"),
                preview = document.createElement("img"),
                container = document.createElement("div");
            var array_images = row.product_images.split(",");

                preview.src = this.assets+product_type+"/"+array_images[0]+".jpg";
                preview.alt = product_type+"#"+row.product_id;
                
                container.appendChild(preview);
                product.appendChild(container);

                preview.addEventListener("mouseenter", event => {
                    console.log(array_images);
                    //here, giving the latest element from the array and not the current selected.
                });

                display_list.appendChild(product);
                
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are trying to opt for mouseover event then you should use mouseover in the place of click event. Currently its not working because the event which you called is a click event.

Comment: Sorry i didn't write correctly, even with mouseover if the selected is example 10 and the latest element from the array is 15, actually when you pass the mouse on the 10 the value inside the event is 15.

Comment: Nvm i just replaced var by let